# search line between two patterns not giving expecting result with

Tags: awk

I need help. In my dump file there are various jobs and I am need to fetch lines between 2 pattern for various jobs from dump.

below are some lines from dump

```
SCHEDULE A01G2A#J01GME2A01 
ON RUNCYCLE RULE2 "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA"
 ON RUNCYCLE CALENDAR1 LAST_DAY
 AT 2330 UNTIL 2345 +1 DAYS 
:
A01A#J01G_R01
OPENS A01GFCDB2A#"/tmp/idreme2a01_create_ob_ac.tkn"
END
```

Like this in dump there are lots of jobs .

I want to take lines from this pattern to **SCHEDULE A02A#J01GME2A01**  to   **END**

I have used below codes

```
awk '/SCHEDULE A02A#J01GME2A01/ {flag=1;next} /END/ {flag=0}flag' A01GFCDB@sche2804.txt
```

But it is searching END in word CALENDAR as well and giving me line o/p but in my requreiment i need lines between first lines till line wihcih start with OPENS or may be some anotehr word.

Can i anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Your bold text isn't matching with your `awk` command. I'm assuming alphanumeric values after `SCHEDULE` are different for each job.

Printing between 2 patterns is already a built in functionality (for `awk` and `sed`):

`awk '/^SCHEDULE/,/^END$/ {print}' file`

Here is a sample run:

```
$ cat file 
SCHEDULE A01G2A#J01GME2A01 
ON RUNCYCLE RULE2 "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA"
 ON RUNCYCLE CALENDAR1 LAST_DAY
 AT 2330 UNTIL 2345 +1 DAYS 
:
A01A#J01G_R01
OPENS A01GFCDB2A#"/tmp/idreme2a01_create_ob_ac.tkn"
END
$ awk '/^SCHEDULE/,/^END$/ {print}' file 
SCHEDULE A01G2A#J01GME2A01 
ON RUNCYCLE RULE2 "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA"
 ON RUNCYCLE CALENDAR1 LAST_DAY
 AT 2330 UNTIL 2345 +1 DAYS 
:
A01A#J01G_R01
OPENS A01GFCDB2A#"/tmp/idreme2a01_create_ob_ac.tkn"
END
```

Comment: Hi Ritesh, In dump there are more line as well for another job which start with schedule and that end with END word, i also early tried this command but somehow o/p of this command is coming with another schedule and end command as well

Comment: @PallviMahajanSapen you can replace the `SCHEDULE` with the text that is specific to a particular job